# How can I troubleshoot a computer that won't shutdown?

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, shutdown

One of my parents work computers running Windows XP won't shutdown properly.

The computer is shutdown normally through the Start menu, but hangs on a system message. This problem occurs at every shutdown (and for some time now), so it's not related to any recent newly installed program.

I've blocked most crapware from starting up, so I'm not sure what could be causing it. From what I've found so far, it could be Roxio even though it's not being launched. I haven't tried booting in Safe Mode yet, but since I blocked almost everything non-essential, I wouldn't know what to look for.

I'd prefer not to force shutting down, as I'd rather figure out what's causing the problem.

Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: what is the system message  being displayed ?

Comment: I wanted to leave this link here, so I could check it later, but ironically it is the message you asked after @Shark: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=307274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a windows XP shutdown update.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307274  Check out http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com to update your computer.

I would recommend a hard reboot (hold the power button down) and startup in safe mode and see if you can at least shut down normally while in safe mode.  You won't corrupt your parent's computer by doing this.  If the computer cannot shutdown properly in safe mode in could by a windows system problem and you can repair windows by booting up with the windows installation disk.

If it shutdowns properly, then you can run a myriad of scans involving antivirus and malware scans.

Look at this program to check for rogue processes. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Scan for malware: http://www.malwarebytes.org/

To scan for virus, burn one or more live cds using the following links: http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-rescue-cd, http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk, http://www.avast.com/bart-cd

What is the system message?  See the following: http://labmice.techtarget.com/windowsxp/TroubleshootingXP/shutdown.htm